# Click event in knockout fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I found out that if you want to prevent firing click event without clicking you have to change your calling to function(){-here-}.

```
self.mainRoutes = ko.observableArray([]);

for (var i=0;i<json.routes.length;i++){
    self.mainRoutes.push( {
        idRoute: json.routes[i].idRoute,
        nameRoute: json.routes[i].name,
        shortRoute: json.routes[i].short,
        descriptionRoute: json.routes[i].description,
        mapRoute: json.routes[i].map,
        col1: json.routes[i].col1,
        col2: json.routes[i].col2,
        col3: json.routes[i].col3
    } );
}

self.hover = ko.observable("0");
self.makeHover = function(folder) {
    self.hover(folder); self.quizDo(); self.changeColors();
};
```

Html:

```
        <section class="mar0" data-bind='foreach: mainRoutes'>
    <div class="stripe40" data-bind='click: function(){$root.makeHover(idRoute)}, css: {gradBlack: idRoute !== $root.hover() ,gradGold: idRoute === $root.hover() ,tGold: idRoute === $root.hover()  }'><h3><span class="numbered" data-bind='text: idRoute'></span> <!--ko text: nameRoute--><!--/ko--></h3></div>
            <div  data-bind='visible: idRoute === $root.hover()'>     

                <p data-bind='text: shortRoute'></p>
                    <div class="l100">
                        <a href="#" class="but-black gradBlack shad-bot mar-bot" data-bind="click: function () {$root.choose('0text','PopText',nameRoute,descriptionRoute,'2routes')}, text: $root.pickONE('aside',4)"></a>
                    </div>
            </div>   
    </section>
```

The problem is with this part: `<div class="stripe40" data-bind='click: ...`

a) I leave click: $root.makeHover(idRoute) => fires automatically

b) I change to: click: function(){$root.makeHover(idRoute)} -> sends wrong values, mostly undefined

Can you help me with editing this part of code? I think the mistake is only there (if I put to the end of code: click:makeHover("0")  = it went through everything, but I reset it at the end of page load.

Comment: Can you post your `makeHover` handler? The syntax `click: function(){ $root.makeHover(idRoute) },` should work fine in theory...

Comment: self.hover = ko.observable("0");
        self.makeHover = function(folder) { self.hover(folder); self.quizDo(); self.changeColors(); };

I realized it does not go to quizDo,.. but goes to changeColors

Comment: What is the structure of mainRoutes?

Comment: `        self.mainRoutes = ko.observableArray([]); 
        for (var i=0;i<json.routes.length;i++) {
            self.mainRoutes.push( 
                {idRoute: json.routes[i].idRoute, 
                nameRoute: json.routes[i].name, 
                shortRoute: json.routes[i].short, 
                descriptionRoute: json.routes[i].description, 
                mapRoute: json.routes[i].map,
                col1: json.routes[i].col1, 
                col2: json.routes[i].col2, 
                col3: json.routes[i].col3}                  
            );
        }`

Comment: try $root.makeHover.bind(idRoute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fsx7f/)

I remove part of your code beucase i didn't have all of it.
If I understand what you want u just need to use

```
click: $root.makeHover
```

In the function you'll receive the route object, i guess its more than necessary for you.